# Java LinkedList with generics

Tags: java, list, generics, data-structures, linked-list

I have been trying to implement a singly linked list in java with generics and I tried to implement a method "headInsert()" to insert a new Node and make it the new head of the list.
I am trying to achieve this by creating a new Node and swapping it with the head. 
However, I have an error while I am trying to parameterize the new Node. 
Here is the code I have written and I would appreciate any sort of help I could get.
Thank you in advance.

```
package datastructures;

public class LinkedList<E> {
private Node head;
private Node tail;
private static class Node<E> {
 E data;
Node next;

 Node (E data) {
    this.data = data;

}

}


//Insert at the beginning of a LinkedList 
public void headInsert(Node n) {
    if(head == null) {
     head = n;

    }    
    else {
        Node temp = head;
        Node n1 = new Node(n1.data);   //error here
        n1.next=head;
        head=n1;
         }
    }
```

Comment: What do you think `n1.data` should refer to? Why do you think so?

Comment: Any why don't you post the error message? Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because `n1` was not created yet when you try to access `n1.data`, it should be:

```
Node n1 = new Node(n.data);
```

That said, you don't really need to create a new node to place in the head. You can implement `headInsert()` like this:

```
public void headInsert(Node n) {
    n.next = this.head;
    this.head = n;
}
```

Suppose you have an empty list (`head` is `null`) and you want to add node `A`, `A.next` will point to `null`, and `head` will point to `A` resulting in the list `A->null`

Now suppose you have a non-empty list, like `A->B->C`, and you want to insert node `Z`, `Z.next` will point to `A`, and `head` will point to `Z` so you will get `Z->A->B->C`.